# Как скрыть некоторые option у тега select на чистом JS

Tags: javascript

У меня есть тег select с тегами option

```
<select id="vid" name="vid[]">
    <option value="1">Мелкая собака</option>
    <option value="2">Средняя собака</option>
    <option value="3">Крупная собака</option>
    <option value="4">Кошка</option>
    <option value="6">Мелкий грызун</option>
    <option value="7">Крупный грызун</option>
    <option value="8">Мелкая птица</option>
    <option value="9">Крупная птица</option>
    <option value="10">Хорек</option>
    <option value="11">Енот</option>
    <option value="12">Минипиг</option>
    <option value="13">Аквариумные рыбки</option>
</select>
```

Как лучше на чистом JS скрыть все элементы option кроме первых трех?

Answer (score 6):

Сначала нужно вытащить все элементы, связанные с этим select'ом - [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

Дальше - вытащить все элементы `option` внутри этого select'a - [document.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName).

Теперь у нас есть список (массив) элементов, над которыми нужно произвести какие-либо действия. Собственно строка `let optionList = document.getElementById('vid').getElementsByTagName('option');` получает все элементы.

Дальше в цикле просто проставляем им `style="display:none;"`

```
<script>
    let optionList = document.getElementById('vid').getElementsByTagName('option');

    for (i = 0; i < optionList.length; i++) {
        if (i > 2) {
            optionList[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none;')
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Хоть в вопросу и написано про `js`, я считаю это перебор.

Предлагаю все таки делать это через `css`:

```css
#vid option:nth-child(n+4) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="vid" name="vid[]">
    <option value="1">Мелкая собака</option>
    <option value="2">Средняя собака</option>
    <option value="3">Крупная собака</option>
    <option value="4">Кошка</option>
    <option value="6">Мелкий грызун</option>
</select>
```

PS: если надо оставить каких-то конкретных животных тогда уже лучше использовать js (определять по содержимому)

Comment: +1, решение действительно значительно лучше и быстрее

Answer (score 4):

```
var option = document.querySelectorAll('option');

  for (let i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
    if (i > 2) {
      option[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
```

Comment: А если у меня есть другие теги select, не захватит ли querySelectorAll('option') их option?

Comment: @Valeriy Petukhov, захватит. Т.к. собираются все option на html странице. Вам надо конкретно из 1 select? Тогда вариант выше будет для вас самым верным :)